# Controller not posting, error Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php

I have modified my controller [Bookscontroller] so that it checks the book's id so that the same book is not borrowed twice but it can't post to the database now.

```
    $model = new Books();


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if(Books::findOne($model->book_id))


        {
         Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger','The book is not available.You can borrow another book another book.');
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'book_id' => $model->book_id]);
    }


    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do not post code as image.

Answer (score -1):

hello if the creat is the method that you are using the action is missing
an attribute called $id 
-so first able your action should be actionCreate($id) and not actionCreate()
-second, see what you are passing on your vue so to use a methode on vue use an array [controller/method , the attribute=>value]